# Vuetify 3 warning: toRefs() expects a reactive object but received a plain one

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I'm using [Vuetify 3 beta 5](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/) with options API in my components. When I either click a `v-select` or hover over a `v-tooltip`, I get a warning in my console: `toRefs() expects a reactive object but received a plain one`. The items I pass to `v-select` and the values passed to `v-tooltip` are normal reactive properties or simple literals.

Is it some mistake on my side that can be easily fixed?

Comment: I can get rid of it by putting `"vuetify": "3.0.0-beta.4"` in my package.json (without caret). Apparently the bug was introduced in version `3.0.0-beta.5`. BTW I think this is a perfecty valid question.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasFeil, this answers my question. Unfortunately it's closed. :(

Comment: So, we have to wait few days until a new Vuetify release will be published. Thanks ! I also think it is a perfectly valid question. Reopen please.

Comment: @TobiasFeil, eightball You can click on the Reopen link under the question.

Comment: It's only showing "Improve this question" for me... but I don't see any way it can be improved, I think it's good as is

Comment: @EugeneBarsky, i don't see any button

Comment: @eightball Sorry. It probably shows up for only those with sufficient reputation points.